# search vue.js with laravel api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

I am trying to make search in a list of elements but when i make the function with vue js i got nothing , in my below code you can see that i got the list and display it in the table successfully but when i try to make search and put the result into a new list i got nothing any help please?

```
<template>
<div class="kt-portlet">

    <div class="kt-portlet__body">
       
        <!--begin::Section-->
        <div class="kt-section">
            <label>
                <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm"  placeholder="Search Here">
            </label>

            <div class="kt-section__content">
                <table class="table" id="datatable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Product Title</th>
                        <th>Product Price</th>
                        <th>Created On</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="teacher in teachers.data" :key="teacher.id">
                        <td>{{teacher.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{teacher.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{teacher.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{teacher.name}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="">
                    <pagination :data="teachers" @pagination-change-page="getTeachers"></pagination>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            teachers:{},
            searchTerm:'',
            employees:{}

        }
    },
    computed:{
        filterSearch(){
            return this.teachers.filter((teacher) => {
                return this.employees = teacher.name.match(this.searchTerm);
            })
        }
    },
    methods:{
       getTeachers(page = 1) {
            axios.get("/api/teachers?page=" + page )

                .then((response)=>
                {
                    this.teachers = response.data;
                })
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getTeachers();
    },


}
```

Comment: Inside filterSearch() method you are assigning not comparing i.e this.employees = teacher.name.match(this.searchTerm); should be this.employees == teacher.name.match(this.searchTerm); or strict comparison with 3 equal sign ===

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```js
filterSearch(){
    return this.teachers.data.filter((teacher) => {
        return this.employees = teacher.name.match(this.searchTerm);
    })
}
```

`teachers.data.filter` vs. `teachers.filter` as you have it — since you are holding an object inside the `teachers`, not an array. Which I'd suggest the opposite - make the teachers the array and in the `getTeachers()` method do `this.teachers = response.data.data`

Then also make the `employees` property an array too. B/c after filtering teachers array within the computed property, you will get an array back, not the object.

If you follow this route - make both teachers and employees an array - then your computed property should not change and it will work as you have it